# w = RsR', solve for R where w, s are known, symmetric and PD. R is orthogonal with det(R)=1

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I have known, symmetric, positive definite matrices $w$ and $s$ such that
$$ w = RsR' $$

I want to solve for/characterize $R$ where $R$ is orthogonal and has determinant one (i.e. is a rotation matrix). Note: ' denotes transpose. All of $w, s, R \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Solutions to $R$ aren't unique (i.e. +/- rotation in 2d) but I'd like to characterize their form.

Thoughts:
Can take eigendecomposition of $w$ and $s$ and, noting that the eigenvalues of $s$ and $d$ are equal, we have:
$$ w = W D W' $$
$$ s = S D S' $$

Substituting into the first equation, we have:
$$ W D W' = R S D S' R' $$
$$ D = W' R S D S' R' W $$

But all I think I can say is that $(W' R S) (S' R' W) = (W' R S) (W' R S)' = I$ which gives no useful characterization of $R$.

We also know that for $w_i, s_i$ the $i^{th}$ eigenvectors of $w, s$ respectively, and $\lambda_i$ their (shared) eigenvalues:
$$ R w_i = s_i $$
$$ w w_i = \lambda_i w_i $$
$$ s s_i = \lambda_i s_i $$

for $i = 1 \dots n$

I can make an overdetermined system of equations from this but I feel like I'm missing something easier. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like $W = RS \rightarrow R = WS'$ is true up to some negation of the columns of $S$. There are $2^n$ possible negations, though half will have determinant $-1$. The solution can thus be found as $\text{\argmin}_R || w - RsR' || $ where $ R = WS' $ is over the possible negations of the columns of $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess:

If you multiply both sides by $R$ on the right you get:

$w R - R s = 0$

Which is a special case of the Sylvester equation:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation

You can form a linear system to solve for $R$ using matrix vectorization:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)

$A r = 0$

Where $r$ here is a column vector. The $r$ with min norm (best solution in the least squares sense) is the right-singular vector of $A$ associated with the smallest singular value. You can find it using SVD:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition

Min norm of SVD solution should enforce $R R' = I$.

Comment: Working this out in Python, and solving in either of two ways: 1. scipy.linalg.solve_sylvester( w, -s, np.zeros_like(w) ) yields the degenerate solution, 0; or 2. Computing the SVD of np.kron(I, w) + np.kron(-s.T, I) and taking the right singular vector with smallest singular value yields a norm on the order of 1e-18 but it is not, in general, a valid rotation matrix.

Comment: I would suggest to project back the resulting $R$ to rotation manifold using polar decomposition. If $R$ is close to a rotation, then it projection to SO manifold would be a good approximation.